# Cannot activate an already activated outlet ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm facing some problems within iOS with my Ionic App. In particular I'm getting this error:

> Cannot activate an already activated outlet ionic:

Where am I wrong?

This is the app-routing-module.ts:

```
    import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './public/register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { 
    path: 'members', 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './members/member-routing.module#MemberRoutingModule'
  },

  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
 ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 

}
```

Comment: Are you using multiple router outlets?

Comment: I've a bottom tab bar for entire app and for each tabs I've different top bar, is this the problem? @Shumail